# No file getting uploaded from postman even after supplying file via firebase

Tags: postman

```
  const upload = async (request, response, next) => {
    const { files } = request;

    if (!files) {
      response.status(400).send({ message: "No file uploaded." });
      return;
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Am I missing something here?

Comment: If you are using Express, are you aware that for `request.files` you have to install appropriate parser package? http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.properties

Comment: Can you upload the whole server file?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it could be as simple as using capitalized `File` instead of `file` for the key name of the file upload in `Body`. If that doesn't work, try inspecting the whole request to see if your middleware is putting the files on a different key in the request object.